# Do I ask for a higher salary, or accept the job since I want to be done looking?

Tags: salary, job-offer, united-states, healthcare-industry

I currently applied to a position a last month at a Healthcare Organization and it was for a Application System Programmer Specialist position. I was notified that I did not receive that position a few weeks later.

I currently am still interning at that HealthCare Org. Yesterday they offered me a position for the Application System Programmer Specialist position and offered me less money then I intended. I talked to my current manager a month ago and he told me the salary range for his position which is somewhat similar.

Below are the ranges. For the Programmer position they want me right away, and would want me to start already next week if I could. The Interface position is still getting approved, but I would get offered it within the next 2 months. I would enjoy both positions, but the programmer one is more of my interest, but the salary is not right.

Application System Programmer Specialist position - 49k starting
Would need to learn a whole new software, since they are rolling in a new software and they want me to be the SME

Interface Specialist - 57k starting
I would know what I am doing, since I have been interning and doing the work.

Is asking for a salary range between 55k and 60k acceptable from this situation?

Comment: 57k... What currency is that? Hard to tell otherwise if it's as good / normal as your manager claims.

Comment: also where you live can affect if that is a good salary or not. What are the job requirements for each?

Comment: @Kozaky It is USD

Comment: Could you clarify the jobs and the sequence of events?   At the end we see Interface Specialist, but the jobs in the earlier text have the same name: Application System Programmer Specialist

Answer (score 3):

There are three pieces to your question.

Should you ask for more money -- **Yes** you should.  What would the harm be in asking, as once your there getting a salary correction of 8 or 9 K will be **difficult**.

The another part you should be thinking about is which one will be more suited to my interests *and* which of these opportunities will provide me more *flexibility for the next job*.

**Summary**:  Consider the cash, opportunity/the enjoyment of the work, and future flexibility (will this help me get the next job).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the area. Look at city data and determine the median income level for that area. That number is usually the level where you're nearly uncomfortable unless you make smart money choices. Factor in things like rent, payments, loans, insurance, food, utilities, unexpected emergencies, etc then that should tell you if it is a good amount. Generally you'll want to make 10-20k more than the median to live comfortably in that area. I base it on nothing other than my personal experience. As a IT field person, you should be making more than the typical white collar job.

To me a developer making 49k USD is not good and not bad. I think asking for 55-60k USD is a smart idea and something you should do during negotiations.

Answer (score 0):

> I am a new graduate.

Take the job. 57k is a lot for a fresh graduate and if you play your cards right, you can move on to higher paying positions very quickly.  HL7 is a really good thing to know, and it it will make you very marketable.

Keep in mind that a lot of healthcare programming isn't really programming at all. Which EHR do they use?

You're one skip away from the big bucks - the database and infrastructure. Try and steer yourself in that direction.